# Celery worker stops working after sending a task

Tags: django, redis, celery

A basic test on a Django/celery environment produce a restarting of the worker every time a new task is sent.

celery==4.1.1
Django==1.10.3
redis==3.0.1

Comment: Errr... I don't mean to be rude, but do you really think anyone can help with so few informations ??? Please edit your post to add a proper MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and _all_ related informations.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I agree with you but ... on my environment just calling a simple debug_task over a simple celery configuration causes a worker restart. Just downgrading redis python package from 3.0.1 to 2.10.3 solves this issue.